# is this redundant? -- import React, { Component } from 'react';

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

at the top of my `Create React App` created file `App.js` is the line `import React, { Component } from 'react';`

Won't `React` import everything already... and if yes then why is `{ Component }` needed?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Importing `Component` separately allows you to use `Component` rather than `React.Component`.  It's a convenience.

Answer (score 2):

It's just a short cut, so that you can write

```
class MyClass extends Component
```

Otherwise you'll have to prefix it.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't use webpack and the Tree Shaking feature then It's just syntax sugar

Many people think this

```
class MyComponent extends Component
```

is more beautiul than

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component
```

But if you're using webpack with tree shaking then webpack will execute dead code elimination in your code

**See more:**

https://webpack.js.org/guides/tree-shaking/